# Twitter Bootstrap - caption using a media-grip

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to deal with adding 'captions' to the Twitter bootstrap MEDIA GRID element. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/vXMMA/73/

You will notice that the 'long' captions make the grid looks 'mis-aligned'. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the `li` elements as `display:inline-block;` in your main css, like so:

```
.media-grid li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  can you explain why this helps?

Comment: @shergill When elements are displayed inline, they lose all block-level qualities and are not contained properly as a block-level element does. They do this by trying to "fit" in as much as possible inline to the content around it, much like text may wrap around an image displayed inline, whilst`inline-block` elements maintain their container boundaries.